# How do I perform a Twilio Flow split by different phone numbers in a channel?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-flex

I am planning to have multiple phone numbers (Whatsapp for example), routed to the same Twilio Flow.

As per https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide, I should be expecting a Twilio phone number that I can use to split the flow by:

```
Flow Variables include:
The Flow's Execution Sid: flow.sid
The Flow's address (e.g. Twilio phone number): flow.channel.address
```

When I tried this on a Whatsapp Sandbox it returned my channel SID instead. How else can I split my flow to different branches depending on my Twilio phone number (not to be mistaken with the customer's phone number) that the customer is connecting with?

*As a note, I understand this can be done by assigning different Flows to different phone numbers, but it seems like an unncessary duplication.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `{{trigger.message.To}}`. That will return the Twilio number the person sent the WhatsApp message to. You can use this varible in the [Split Based on Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/split-based-on) to route to to a particular path in the shared Studio flow.

You can look at the Studio execution logs for for your Studio flow (under Logs > Click an Execution SID > Expand Trigger > Click on Widget & Flow Properties).

Comment: Thanks @Alan. I have just tried that and and `{{trigger.message.To}}` returned the same value as `{{trigger.message.ChannelSid}}`. I am not sure if this could just be a Whatsapp Sandbox specific issue, and will resolve itself once I move out of sandbox?

Comment: After some fiddling around, `trigger.message.ChannelAttributes.twilioNumber` gave me what I was looking for. Marking your solution anyway as that led me to look at the right place

Comment: It sounds like possibly Twilio Flex is involved somewhere?

Comment: yes I am using Flex to manage the conversations but didn't think that would cause any complications in the studio layer of things?

Comment: Flex just handles some fo the messaging differently vs. sending it directly into Studio.

Comment: Fair enough, I just figured out that Flex doesn't handle whatsapp location messages yet hah, so definitely taking your word that it works differently